# How to parse XML and how to use XMLOpen

Tags: xml, windev

Most XML Functions require a name for the xml document. But there's no way in XMLOpen to specify such a name. Is there another way to parse xml from an url?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use XMLDocument and not XMLOpen if you want to name your document, XMLDocument work with a name and a source code and XLMOpen work with a variable from type xmlDocument.